# R: Obtain aggregations of two or more variables by two or more grouping variables

Tags: r

With the following dataframe I need to obtain monthly sums of the following two variables: "CallsHandled" and "Engaged"
 By the following grouping variables: "Month","ID","Location","LANGUAGE","MemRegion"

```
structure(list(Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Week = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L), ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A1234", 
"F1234"), class = "factor"), Location = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Corona", "Denver"), class = "factor"), LANGUAGE = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("English", "Spanish"), class = "factor"), 
MemRegion = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NCAL", 
"SCAL"), class = "factor"), CallsHandled = c(1L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), Engaged = c(120L, 30L, 1243L, 75L, 45L, 55L, 
200L, 120L, 30L, 230L, 2065L, 45L, 55L, 200L, 1483L, 30L, 
1243L, 75L, 45L, 55L), QueueA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
QueueB = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), QueueC = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L)), .Names = c("Month", "Week", "ID", "Location", "LANGUAGE", 
"MemRegion", "CallsHandled", "Engaged", "QueueA", "QueueB", "QueueC"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Additionally, in order to include "Queues A:C" as grouping variables, would I have to combine them into a single column? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 parts to this question, firstly how do you group things up and sum, and secondly how could you combine Queue A:C into one column.

For the first question you can use the library `dplyr` which makes it a lot easier and more intuitive.

```
df <- structure(list(Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                     Week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), 
                     ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A1234", "F1234"), class = "factor"), 
                     Location = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Corona", "Denver"), class = "factor"), 
                     LANGUAGE = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("English", "Spanish"), class = "factor"), 
                     MemRegion = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NCAL", "SCAL"), class = "factor"), 
                     CallsHandled = c(1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                     Engaged = c(120L, 30L, 1243L, 75L, 45L, 55L, 200L, 120L, 30L, 230L, 2065L, 45L, 55L, 200L, 1483L, 30L, 1243L, 75L, 45L, 55L), 
                     QueueA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     QueueB = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
                     QueueC = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Month", "Week", "ID", "Location", "LANGUAGE", "MemRegion", "CallsHandled", "Engaged", "QueueA", "QueueB", "QueueC"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Month, ID, Location, LANGUAGE) %>%
  mutate(TotalCallsHandled = sum(CallsHandled),
         TotalEngaged = sum(Engaged))
```

So firstly, we use `group_by` to group by specifically the variables you have listed, and mutate to sum everything up, and this will do what you think intuitively.

For combining everything into one column, there are probably many ways to do this, but probably the most straight forward way is to create some kind of unique identifier for each column and combine all the columns into one.

```
df$Queue <- as.factor(df$QueueA + df$QueueB*2 + df$QueueC*3)
levels(df$Queue) <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

Since everything should be a 0, 1 flag, we can recreate the flags to be `1 -> A`, `2 -> B`, `3 -> C`, and then relevel the factors to be A, B, C again. Then we can simply use `group_by` function again to get the intended result as above.

```
df %>% group_by(Month, ID, Location, LANGUAGE, Queue) %>%
  mutate(TotalCallsHandled = sum(CallsHandled),
         TotalEngaged = sum(Engaged)) %>%
  select(-QueueA, -QueueB, -QueueC)
```

With output:

```
Source: local data frame [20 x 11]
Groups: Month, ID, Location, LANGUAGE, Queue

   Month Week    ID Location LANGUAGE MemRegion CallsHandled Engaged Queue
1      1    1 F1234   Denver  English      NCAL            1     120     B
2      1    2 F1234   Corona  Spanish      SCAL            1      30     C
3      1    3 F1234   Corona  English      NCAL            8    1243     B
4      1    4 F1234   Corona  Spanish      NCAL            1      75     A
5      1    5 F1234   Corona  Spanish      SCAL            1      45     A
6      1    6 F1234   Denver  English      SCAL            2      55     B
7      1    7 F1234   Corona  English      NCAL            1     200     C
8      1    8 F1234   Corona  English      NCAL            1     120     B
9      1    9 F1234   Denver  English      NCAL            1      30     A
10     1   10 F1234   Corona  Spanish      NCAL            1     230     C
11     1    1 A1234   Corona  English      NCAL           10    2065     C
12     1    2 A1234   Corona  English      SCAL            1      45     A
13     1    3 A1234   Corona  Spanish      NCAL            3      55     A
14     1    4 A1234   Corona  English      NCAL            1     200     A
15     1    5 A1234   Corona  English      SCAL            8    1483     B
16     1    6 A1234   Denver  English      SCAL            1      30     B
17     1    7 A1234   Corona  Spanish      SCAL            6    1243     C
18     1    8 A1234   Corona  Spanish      SCAL            1      75     B
19     1    9 A1234   Corona  Spanish      SCAL            1      45     C
20     1   10 A1234   Corona  English      SCAL            2      55     B
Variables not shown: TotalCallsHandled (int), TotalEngaged (int)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I just ran but my dataframe is the same size with rows that look to be repeats now. have I done something wrong? I thought by grouping and summarizing I would reduce the size of my dataframe (albeit slightly because I have so many grouping variables in this example).

Comment: When I apply suggestion to actual dataset, here are 2 of 14 Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(jan15r$CLAIMS, 2) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(jan15r$CONTENT, jan15r$CLAIMS * 2) :
  ‘+’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: I have no idea what your column CLAIMS is

Comment: I created QueuesA:C as names for this sample dataframe so I could try and make the question simpler. My real dataframe has telephone Queue headings (14 of them)like "CLAIMS",  "CREDIT_CARD", "DEDUCT_BILL", etc. with a binary 1 value if the call was related to one of those respective categories, and a 0 if not. They are just dummy variables like my sample dataframe but when I try to reproduce your coding example and extend it out to 14 variables using the real names, I get errors that look like this:

Comment: These are the Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(jan15r$CLAIMS, 2) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(jan15r$CONTENT, jan15r$CLAIMS * 2) :
  ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(jan15r$CREDIT_CARD, 3) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(jan15r$DEDUCT_BILL, 4) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(jan15r$HCREFORM, 5) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Where do you get this warning, and if they belong to multiple queues then my code won't work. (you didn't mention it in the question, nor is there a logical solution if the groupings are not mutaully exclusive...)

Comment: the warnings occur when the command is run. The new variable is created and attached to the dataframe but all the values are "NA". Those categories are mutually exclusive.  Your coding works terrifically on the sample dataframe I provided when I run it, just not on a sample from my real dataframe and I can't figure out why. I think that all I am doing is substituting the real variable names for the ones in my sample.

Comment: @user3594490 The warnings seem to indicate that the values in your real data are being stored as factors, not integers, as in your example.  Call `str(your.real.data)` to see if they are in fact factors.  If so, that's the culprit.  You can't multiply or add factors, which is what the warning is all about.  Using your example data, try `factor(dat$QueueA) + factor(dat$QueueB)` and see the warning.

Answer (score 0):

To make the `Queue` variables into a single factor variable, you could do this:

```
queues <- which(dat[ , c("QueueA", "QueueB", "QueueC")]==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
queues<-queues[
            order(queues[,"row"]), "col"]
queues<-factor(queues, labels=c("QueueA", "QueueB", "QueueC"))
dat <- data.frame(dat, queues)
```

Though, @chappers approach for this is nicer.

Then, you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(dat[,c("CallsHandled", "Engaged")], 
    by=list(dat$Month, dat$ID, dat$Location, dat$LANGUAGE, dat$MemRegion, dat$queues),
    sum)

#   Group.1 Group.2 Group.3 Group.4 Group.5 Group.6 CallsHandled Engaged
#1        1   A1234  Corona English    NCAL  QueueA            1     200
#2        1   F1234  Denver English    NCAL  QueueA            1      30
#3        1   A1234  Corona Spanish    NCAL  QueueA            3      55
#4        1   F1234  Corona Spanish    NCAL  QueueA            1      75
#5        1   A1234  Corona English    SCAL  QueueA            1      45
#6        1   F1234  Corona Spanish    SCAL  QueueA            1      45
#7        1   F1234  Corona English    NCAL  QueueB            9    1363
#8        1   F1234  Denver English    NCAL  QueueB            1     120
#9        1   A1234  Corona English    SCAL  QueueB           10    1538
#10       1   A1234  Denver English    SCAL  QueueB            1      30
#11       1   F1234  Denver English    SCAL  QueueB            2      55
#12       1   A1234  Corona Spanish    SCAL  QueueB            1      75
#13       1   A1234  Corona English    NCAL  QueueC           10    2065
#14       1   F1234  Corona English    NCAL  QueueC            1     200
#15       1   F1234  Corona Spanish    NCAL  QueueC            1     230
#16       1   A1234  Corona Spanish    SCAL  QueueC            7    1288
#17       1   F1234  Corona Spanish    SCAL  QueueC            1      30
```

Answer (score 0):

@chappers solution aggregates correctly but leaves me with a bunch of duplicate rows for some reason that I can't figure out. This works for factors and reduces the number of rows in my actual dataframe (no duplicates):

```
aggregate(cbind(CallsHandled,Engaged~Month + ID + Location + LANGUAGE + MemRegion, data=df, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```